# What is "Offers Apple Watch App" label meaning?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I have iPhone app and want to add support for Apple Watch as well.

From the development standpoint it means I should develop separate app for Apple Watch too, or it just enough to add some support into main app?

I see such label as "Offers Apple Watch App" in App Store, but don't know what is behind the scene (separate app, or just some line of code to add this Watch support).

So main question is - what is "Offers Apple Watch App" label meaning?
And second question is - how to add Apple Watch support into iPhone app.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reading through the docs, or any of the tutorials available online? What did you not understand from there?

Comment: I thought there is some easy way to add Apple Watch support - without developing an Watch app actually.

Comment: That would have been in the docs ;)

Comment: It's ok, I'm ready to cut my teeth on Apple Watch programming )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Apple Watch apps must be accompanied by a containing iPhone app.  To include an Apple Watch portion you must add the WatchKit extension to your main iOS app and create a new target.  When this package is uploaded to the App Store it automatically adds that "Offers Apple Watch App" label to your listing.

See Apple's documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html